# Magento 2 Checkout Next button rename

Tags: checkout

I want to change the name of the Next button in checkout page. I am overriding the shipping.html file to change the name of next button but its not working even i have run deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to over-ride the shipping.html file inside your custom theme with the following path:

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

IF this doesn't work, try removing the following:

1. sudo rm -rf pub/static/*
2. sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
3. sudo rm -rf generated/*

Re-run setup:upgrade etc... and clear caches